# Total characters (not code units) of a String in Java considering Supplementary Characters

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

How can you obtain the total characters of a String, considering that it could have supplementary characters which takes 2 code units to be encoded.

Example:

```
String strTest = "a"; //Supplementary character
System.out.println(strTest.length());
```

Output:

```
3
```

As we can see if we use length() we obtain 3 instead of 2. What I want to obtain is the number of characters for a given String, not the number of code units.

Comment: You'll need a proper, Unicode-aware text processing library. "Text" is a very nontrivial concept that goes far beyond the notion of a array of variables.

Comment: The term character is a bit ambiguous. For example, the grapheme é could still be 2 code points if it is in [NFD form](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms).

Comment: I think we can understand the question as asking how to count the code *points* (instead of code *units*) of a `java.lang.String`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
string.codePointCount(0, string.length())
```