# How to put a supplementary Unicode character in a string literal?

Tags: java, unicode

How to put a supplementary Unicode character (say, codepoint [10400](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/Supplementary/010400.gif)) in a string literal?
I have tried putting a surrogate pair like this:

```
String text = "TEST \uD801\uDC00";
System.out.println(text);
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

UPDATE:

The good news is, the string is constructed properly.
Byte array in UTF-8: 54 45 53 54 20 f0 90 90 80
Byte array in UTF-16: fe ff 0 54 0 45 0 53 0 54 0 20 d8 1 dc 0

But the bad news is, it is not printed properly (in my Fedora box) and I can see a square instead of the expected symbol (my console didn't support unicode properly).

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn’t seem to work? What is the value of `text.charAt(5)`?

Comment: It doesn't print the symbol properly. It could be something with the output stream.

Comment: I believe that "a little box" is used to represent a character for which the system cannot display.  This may simply mean that the font that is used in your display where you are trying to view the output does not provide a glyph for that character.

Comment: That's right, my console didn't support unicode properly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"Works for me", what exactly is the issue?

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    int cp = 0x10400;
    String text = "test \uD801\uDC00";
    System.out.println("cp:    " + cp);
    System.out.println("found: " + text.codePointAt(5));
    System.out.println("len:   " + text.length());
}
```

Output:

```
cp:    66560
found: 66560
len:   7
```

Note that length -- like most String methods -- deals with `char`s, not Unicode characters. So much for awesome Unicode support :)

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like there's something wrong with the output stream, since the byte[] I get from text.getBytes() is right.

Comment: @houman001 Remember to *always* -- except in those cases I do now know about ;) -- specify an encoding with `getBytes` :) Lest it "encodes this String into a sequence of bytes **using the platform's default charset**". Similar holds for `new String(byte[])`. If the correct encoding is used (specified or otherwise) then the output sent to the stream should be correct: but the program (or terminal) on the other side might not agree.

Comment: Interesting that `text.length()` returns 7. Which means that Java thinks in terms of `16-bit UTF-16 Codepoints`. So my rule of thumb is: Despite java calls it a `Character` type, it is really `UTF16 Codepoint` type. Which will be synonymous to what we think a character is whilst we represent characters with `Unicode Codepoint below 0xFFFF`. However if we want to represent in java a character with `Unicode codepoint U+10346`, then string, containing it, will be of length `2`.(Via 2 'surrogate' `UTF16 codepoints`). If you check `stringWithUx10346.charAt(0).isSurrogate()` would return `true`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502030/total-characters-not-code-units-of-a-string-in-java-considering-supplementary

Answer (score 5):

It is supposed to work using:

```
System.out.println(
    "text = " + new String(Character.toChars(h))
);
```

But the output is:

```
text = ?
```

Comment: Assuming h is correct: `System.out` encodes data to the system default charset (this can be a lossy conversion); the device you are writing to must use the same charset (not always the case); the device must have font support for the grapheme you want to display.

Comment: Not to mention that if we're talking about the Windows console: when accessed using the stdio functions as Java does, it's broken and can't cope with characters outside the ANSI code page at all (let alone characters from the Astral Planes).