# Draw fontawesome to bitmap

Tags: android, notifications, font-awesome

I want to draw an icon from fontawesome to a notification view in android. To do so I tried to draw this icon to a Bitmap, to set the typeface, and then set the Bitmap in the notification view.

I use this code:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 50, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),"fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setSubpixelText(true);
paint.setTypeface(typeface);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setTextSize(15);
myCanvas.drawText("&#xf29d;", 0, 20, paint);
notificationView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.activity, myBitmap);
```

But all it shows is `"&#xf29d;"` and no icon. In other contexts the fontawesome works just fine.

Comment: `drawText()` is not going to convert an HTML-style entity reference for you on its own.

Comment: OK, you got an idea what I can change to make it work?

Comment: Try `"\u"` notation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8062048/115145 http://javajee.com/unicode-escapes-in-java

Comment: Thanks, thats it. Changing to myCanvas.drawText("\uf29d;", 0, 20, paint); worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&#xf29d;` is an HTML-style entity reference. Most places in Android will just treat that as a sequence of characters with no particular meaning.

In your case, the simplest solution is to use Java Unicode string literal syntax, replacing the `&#x` with `\u` and removing the `;`, giving you `"\uf29d"`.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, you should use "\uf29d" format.

Example,
uniCode = "\uf29d" 
canvas.drawText(uniCode, x, y, paint); 
or
canvas.drawText("\uf29d", x, y, paint);